# How do I add dependencies to grandchildren projects from root?

Tags: gradle

I have a multi level nested project which goes to 3 levels and I would like to add a dependency to the 3rd level from root project `build.gradle` file. How do I do that?

For example, I have the following project structure. GP (GrandParent) is at the root, P1 and P2 are direct subprojects under GP, and GC1 and GC2 are subprojects under P1 and GC3 and GC4 are subprojects under P2.

GP
|____ P1
...........|____GC1
...........|____GC2

|____ P2
...........|____ GC3
.......... |____ GC4

From GP's build.gradle, I want to add dependencies to GC1, GC2, GC3 and GC4. So I tried the following in `build.gradle` of GP:

```
configure(subprojects) {
   compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jul-to-slf4j', version: '1.7.7'
}
```

It fails with this message when it is trying to process GC1, GC2, GC3 or GC4, but passes for P1 and P2.

> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection) values: [file collection]
>     Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)

My `settings.gradle`:

```
include 'P1', 'P1:GC1', 'P1:GC2',...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a correct message from gradle. Indeed there's no such method. What you're missing is a `dependencies` block. So it should be:

```
configure(subprojects) {
  dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jul-to-slf4j', version: '1.7.7'
  }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/34822718) you can find a demo. Run `gradle :P1:GC1:printDeps` to verify it works.